# Verificar si la ventana está abierta o no

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

quiero verificar que si la ventana esté en "true" la cierre bajando la opacidad a 0, y si la ventana está en false suba la opacidad a 1

```
function one() {
     var abierto;
     if (abierto == true) {
      abierto = false;
      document.getElementById('settings-popover').style.opacity = '0';
     } else
     {
         document.getElementById('settings-popover').style.opacity = '1';
          abierto = true;
     }
}
```

pero con este código tengo el problema en el que la ventana solamente abre, ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que abre y cierre?

Comment: solo debes porner el `var abierto` afuera de la funcion!

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias @Bryro!

Answer (score 0):

No tiene sentido crear la variable `abierto`, porque puedes analizar el estado actual de la ventana, en todo caso y para simplificar, crea una variable para identificar la ventana:

```
function one() {
     // Crear variable para la ventana
     let ventana = document.getElementById('settings-popover');
     // Analizar valor actual
     if(ventana.style.opacity == '1') {
         // Ocultar
         ventana.style.opacity = '0';
     } else {
         // Mostrar
         ventana.style.opacity = '1';
     }
}
```

Comment: `ventana.style.opacity = ventana.style.opacity == '1' ? '0' : '1';`

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob, sí, la asignación ternaria es muy buena para estos casos.